# Track won't go all the way to the end with position: relative

Tags: javascript, html, css

The image track stops about a third of the way through and no matter what I change, it won't budge.

I tried changing the scroll percentage but that just messed up the animations :(

I know the problem is the fact that it's no longer `position: absolute`, but absolute positions won't work when I'm trying to center it within the wrapper `div` built into the larger website.

I updated the JavaScript today to make it only slide for the `div`, but nothing changed yet :(

```js
const track = document.getElementById("image-track");

const handleOnDown = e => {
  if (!track.contains(e.target)) return;
  track.dataset.mouseDownAt = e.clientX;
};

const handleOnUp = () => {
  track.dataset.mouseDownAt = "0";
  track.dataset.prevPercentage = track.dataset.percentage;
};

const handleOnMove = e => {
  if (track.dataset.mouseDownAt === "0") return;
  const mouseDelta = parseFloat(track.dataset.mouseDownAt) - e.clientX;
  const maxDelta = window.innerWidth / 2;
  const percentage = (mouseDelta / maxDelta) * -100;
  const nextPercentageUnconstrained = parseFloat(track.dataset.prevPercentage) + percentage;
  const nextPercentage = Math.max(Math.min(nextPercentageUnconstrained, 0), -100);
  track.dataset.percentage = nextPercentage;
  track.animate({
    transform: `translate(${nextPercentage}%, -50%)`
  }, {
    duration: 1200,
    fill: "forwards"
  });
  for (const image of track.getElementsByClassName("image")) {
    image.animate({
      objectPosition: `${100 + nextPercentage}% center`
    }, {
      duration: 1200,
      fill: "forwards"
    });
  }
};

window.onmousedown = e => handleOnDown(e);
window.ontouchstart = e => handleOnDown(e.touches[0]);
window.onmouseup = e => handleOnUp(e);
window.ontouchend = e => handleOnUp(e.touches[0]);
window.onmousemove = e => handleOnMove(e);
window.ontouchmove = e => handleOnMove(e.touches[0]);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 99.5%;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #bfb398;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  color: #9D000D;
}

#image-track {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4vmin;
  position: relative;
  top: 32%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  user-select: none;
  /* -- Prevent image highlighting -- */
}

#image-track>.image {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 40vmin;
  height: 56vmin;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 100% center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Famously Good!</h1>
  <div id="image-track" data-mouse-down-at="0" data-prev-percentage="0">
    <img class="image" src="Images/Miley-Cyrus-Leopolds.jpg" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="Images/Tom-Cruise-Leopolds.jpg" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="Images/William-Macy_Leopolds.jpg" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="Images/Paula-Deen-Leopolds.jpg" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="Images/Mini-Anden-Niki-Taylor-Leopolds.jpg" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="Images/Alan-Rickman-Leopolds.jpg" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="Images/Kimberly-Schlapman-Leopolds.jpg" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="Images/Patti-LuPone-Leopolds.jpg" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="Images/Philip-Hoffman-Leopolds.jpg" draggable="false" />
  </div>
</div>
```